# Building float values using buffer nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm  reading 32Bit float in form of 2x16 Bits. to build the value I'm trying to use Nodejs **Buffer** function as followed :

```
// Create new Buffer based on array bytes
var buf = Buffer.from([0x122f, 0x3A53]);

// Represent these bytes as 32-bit unsigned int
const value = buf.readUInt32BE();

// save the value
msg.payload = value;

return msg;
```

I'm running this on Node-red, and I get the following error:

```
RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: Attempt to write outside buffer bounds
```

any idea  what I'm doing wrong here ?
thanks in advance !

**Update**
After @hardillb answer, the error has been solved, nevertheless, I still can get the float values ?
here is  what  I get :

[image]

so the question is how to build float out those 2 uint16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how you are defining the Buffer. `Buffer.from()` is expecting an [array of bytes](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array), not 2 16bit numbers

You can do it by writing the 16bit numbers to a new buffer e.g.

```
var buf = Buffer.alloc(4);
buf.writeUInt16BE(0x122f);
buf.writeUInt16BE(0x3a53);

msg.payload = buf.readUInt32BE();
return msg;
```

To build it from an array of 16bit values already in `msg.payload`

```
var buf = Buffer.alloc(msg.payload.length * 2)
for (var i=0; i< msg.payload.length); i++) {
  buf.writeUInt16BE(msg.payload[i], (i*2));
}

msg.payload = buf.readUInt32BE();
return msg;
```

Comment: Exactly the same way, just loop over the array to write them to the buffer

Comment: what do you mean exactly, sorrry don't get it ?